# Hardhat install is falling to install

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to run the cmd

`npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.1" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"`

When running i receive this error log

```
 npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.1" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tracking@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: ethers@5.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ethers
npm ERR!   ethers@"^5.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer ethers@"^6.1.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@3.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers
npm ERR!   peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@"^3.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
npm ERR!     dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@"3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@"^3.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers
npm ERR!     peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@"^2.0.0" from @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@3.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
npm ERR!       dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@"3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-24T20_39_45_411Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\liamr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-24T20_39_45_411Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\liamr\tracking>
```

I first did `npm i hardhat` which came with no problem, then I did `npx hardahat`, did all of the requirements and it then said that  `You need to install these dependencies to run the sample project: npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.1" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"`, I accidently did npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.1" without the last hardhat toolbox, I then realised my mistake and I am stuck here as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `ethers` library installed with version `5.7.2`.

But `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` of version `3.0.0` which you are trying to install requires `6.1.0` of `ethers`. Hence the version mismatch.

You can do either of the two approaches here:

1. Downgrade your version of `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`. So instead of trying to install latest version, try v2.

```
npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2
```

2. Update your version of `ethers` already installed in your project.

```
npm uninstall ethers
npm install -S ethers
```

Then install your hardhat packages.

Comment: I would love to but currently I dont have high enough rep to upvote as of now.  But as soon as i do, I will upvote you.

Comment: Hey I have just checked and I have upvoted you just then, kind regards